# Mysql stuck with a syntax error... won't let me access table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

First, I want to be clear I am NOT asking a syntax question.

I'm using PHPmyadmin to work on my DB.  I made a typo with my query and of course it gave me the following syntax error:

> SQL query: Documentation
>
> SELECT * FROM `order_detail` where product_quantity > 1 AND
>   total_price_tax_incl <> total_price_tax_excl AND 
>   total_shipping_price_tax_incl <> "0.000000" ORDER BY `id_order` ASC
>   and`total_shipping_price_tax_incl`>0   LIMIT 0, 25  MySQL said:
>   Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'and`total_shipping_price_tax_incl`>0  LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

So I fixed it, got the SAME error.  And I mean "same".  I can now do something simple like SELECT * FROM `order detail` and I still get the identical error!  I don't mean a different error with my new command, I mean the exact same error referencing the exact same syntax mistake that I'm no longer typing in.

I've tried restarting the SQL server.  The issue only affects this one table.  I have a backup, but it is an hour old I'm actively working on it and I made a lot of changes I'd rather not have to do over.

HELP!

Comment: You're putting `AND col > 0` *after* your `ORDER BY` clause. You can't do that,

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question

Comment: As mentioned by bcsteeve it must be a caching issue. I had same problem in Google Chrome. I guess my table got corrupted and started giving this error. It kept there regardless or my restarting wamp server and even re-importing the entire database. I even deleted entire database and re-imported from old dump but it still there. Then I found this post, cleared my cache and it worked. Thanks for this question.

Comment: believe me SE is proving to be a less favorite place for less educated programmers like me. They wont help you but vote you down!

Comment: I'm glad my -3 rated question helped someone :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Browser issue.  I loaded it up in Opera (was using Chrome) and now it works.  Must be a caching problem.